# Define a single drawable for a button and change it depending on the selected MeterialDesign theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

I have an ImageButton which uses drawable/sampleimage.xml as source and I am using MaterialDesign for my application theme.

My layout for the button looks like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sampleButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sampleimage.xml" />
```

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I change my theme with the setting in Android 10 or with

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

and

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

on Android 9.

I dont how how to define a single drawable for my button which changes depending on the selected theme.
I want to use drawable/sampleimage_light.xml for the light theme and drawable/sampleimage_dark.xml when using the dark theme.

Comment: You can create night mode drawable resource in `drawable-night` folder and they should be automatically used.

Comment: @Pawel thanks, i will try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My drawables are vector images, so i just changed the fill color to ?attr/colorOnSurface

My drawable now looks like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="?attr/colorOnSurface"
        android:pathData="M8,5v14l11,-7z"/>
</vector>
```